# How to find out which class pushed me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

How can I find out inside of a pushed VC, which VC called this function (who is calling me to arrive):

**in .m of calling controller:**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:calledViewController animated:YES];
```

**in .m of called controller:**

```
NSString* class = [self.navigationController whoCalledMe];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.navigationController.viewControllers` is an array of view controller pushed on to stack of `UINavigationController`.
So, last one is your "`self`" (`calledViewController`).

 Last but one is the one which pushed (`whoCalledMe`).

So,

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self.navigationController.viewControllers
    [self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2] class]);
```

Also remember to check that there are **at least 2 view controllers**  in the array.

Comment: Remember to check if there is actually a view controller after current. I've seen behavior where one view controller would push a view controller, then after the animation ends, it would remove itself from the view controllers.

Comment: Also remember to check that there are 2 view controllers at least in the array (ex: Somehow the user manages to go to that page while it being the root view controller), cause otherwise you're looking at object at index -1.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :-

```
if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1){
    UIViewController* vc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:
      self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2]);
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([vc class])}
}
```

Comment: This answer seems better and safer